# Defining a string within AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android

Is there any way possible to define a  or other data type within AndroidManifest.xml , such that other tags such as  or  can refer to the value contained within the string?

```
<?xml version=1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <string name="foo" value="bar">
    <application>
        <activity>
            <meta-data android:name="metadata1" android:value="@string/foo"/>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

EDIT: Purpose

The reason for wishing to contain string data within the Manifest is for packaging up multiple versions of the same app, ie English, French versions will need to know about different expansion file sizes.

To achieve the desired result, Manifests are generated which have the various pieces of meta-data to denote such differences.

Comment: Why do you want them to be in the manifest instead of strings.xml?

Comment: The manifest is used for the phone to read vital information about the app, like system permissions it requires use of and what versions of Android it supports. A separate .xml file in res/values is the standard location for storing strings

Comment: I've added details above towards the purpose, the reason to not use strings is because it would require creation of a separate project for every package I'd like to create.

Answer (score 2):

Not in the manifest but you can define it in res/values/strings.xml - eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="foo">bar</string>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve my result, I've put  as a child of  instead of each activity.

Of useful note, I'm using merging of Android Manifests to this effect:

Library:

```
<?xml version=1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">        
    <application>
        <activity></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MyProject:

```
<?xml version=1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <meta-data android:name="metadata1" android:value="StringLocalValue"/>
</manifest>
```

Then I have each activity access the data:

```
ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
ai.metaData.getString("metadata1");
```

This means that activities can be defined in a parent library project, and data can be stored within child AndroidManifests.