# Firebase messaging: default notification channel doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

When I send notifications from Firebase console without channel specified on Android Oreo it must use "Miscellaneous" channel **OR** if provided default channel from Android manifest. So I create and provide default channel in my app:

```
// Application onCreate
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) 
            as NotificationManager
    val channelId = getString(R.string.notification_channel_id)
    if(manager.getNotificationChannel(channelId)==null) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId,
                getString(R.string.notification_channel_name),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        channel.description = 
                getString(R.string.notification_channel_description)
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}

// Manifest
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel"
    android:value="@string/notification_channel_id" />
```

But it doesn't work. Notifications always use "Miscellaneous" channel. Am I missing something here or is it a Firebase bug?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

apologies, apparently the documentation has not been updated properly :(

The correct metadata in the manifest is:

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
   android:value="@string/notification_channel_id" />
```

Note the `_id` at the end of the `android:name` attribute value.

Will get the documentation updated asap.

Comment: Now it works, thanks. I delivered PR with fix to quickstart-android repo.

Comment: how you can created **notification_channel_id**

Comment: @MaheshGawhane    <string name="default_notification_channel_id">default</string>

Comment: @TigranSarkisian - and where does that go please ?

Comment: The <string> goes in android/app/src/main/res/values/string.xml (you may need to create it).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16424125/16913341

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="default_notification_channel_id">default</string>
</resources>